# “Is this understanding correct?” anything more polite than this?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, conversation

Do we have a more polite way to say “Is this understanding correct?”.
I often find it a little tough question to ask to clients.

Anything that sounds more polite and means the same? And also, is the above question grammatically correct?

Comment: Can we have some context, please? Are you asking about your understanding of their problem, or their understanding of your solution?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, In context of understanding their problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To confirm whether you have understood the client's issue, the question is fine, if not particularly idiomatic.

> So, you have problems A and B, and you need to do C as well. Is this understanding correct?

There's nothing wrong with that. You could alter the question slightly:

> Is my understanding correct?
>   Have I got that right?
>   Is there anything else?

If you want to find out whether *they* have understood, you might need to be a little more tangential. For example, don't say this:

> That means you will need to do A and B in order that C can be made available. Do you understand?

That may well be considered rude. You'd need to ask about how you have handled the situation.

> Have I explained that well enough?
>   Is there anything else I need to tell you?

Comment: Thanks. Nice that you added a scenario to explain it :-)

Answer (score 5):

I would try "Is my understanding of this correct?".  That subtly implies that the possible fault lies with you not them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about your understanding of what someone else has said

> "Is what I have understood correct?"

If you're talking about their understanding of what you've said

> "Have you understood?"

Comment: The OP was asking for polite ways, and I think "Have you understood?" sounds very rude. See, for example, @AndrewLeach's answer.